# Server using SSL returns "no certificate returned"

Tags: c, sockets, ssl, openssl

I'm trying to do an echo server using SSL and verifying certificates of both sides. The socket connection seems to work perfectly but the SSL_Accept on the server returns error. The error is:

```
CONEXION: 127.0.0.1:55387 3073529532:error:140890B2:SSL routines: \
SSL3_GET_CLIENT_CERTIFICATE:no certificate returned:s3_srvr.c:3283:
```

This is the client code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>


//carga los certificados como en el servidor    
void CargaCertificados(SSL_CTX* ctx, char* CertFile, char* KeyFile){

    /* setea el certificado local */
    if (SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, CertFile , SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0){
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }

    /* setea la clave privada */
    if ( SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, KeyFile, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0 ){
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }

    /* verifica la clave prievada */
    if ( !SSL_CTX_check_private_key(ctx) ){
        fprintf(stderr, "la clave privada no coincide con el certificado publico\n");
        abort();
    }
}

//conecta el socket como en las practicas anteriores
int ConectaSocket(const char *hostname, int port){
    int sd;
    struct hostent *host;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;

    if ( (host = gethostbyname(hostname)) == NULL ){
        perror(hostname);
        abort();
    }

    sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    bzero(&addr, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = *(long*)(host->h_addr);

    if ( connect(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0 ){
        close(sd);
        perror(hostname);
        abort();
    }
    return sd;
}

//inicializa el contexto a traves de una instancia
SSL_CTX* InitCTX(void){

    SSL_CTX *ctx;

    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();  /* carga los cifrados etc */
    SSL_load_error_strings();   /* carga los mensajes de error */

    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method());   /* crea un nuevo contexto con la instancia del cliente*/
    if ( ctx == NULL ){
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }
    return ctx;
}

//muestra los certificados
void MuestraCertificados(SSL* ssl){

    X509 *cert;
    char *line;

    cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl); /* coge el certificado del servidor */
    if ( cert != NULL ){

        printf("CERTIFICADOS EN EL CLIENTE:\n");
        line = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), 0, 0);
        printf("SUJETO: %s\n", line);
        free(line);       
        line = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_issuer_name(cert), 0, 0);
        printf("EMISOR: %s\n", line);
        free(line);       
        X509_free(cert);     
    }
    else
        printf("NO EXISTEN CERTIFICADOS.\n");
}

int main(int argc, char*argv[]){

    SSL_CTX *ctx;
    int server;
    SSL *ssl;
    char buf[1024];
    int bytes;
    char msg[100];

    if(argc != 4)
        return -1;


    SSL_library_init();

    ctx = InitCTX();
    CargaCertificados(ctx, argv[2], argv[3]);
    server = ConectaSocket("localhost", atoi(argv[1]));

    ssl = SSL_new(ctx);      /* crea el estado de conexion SSL */
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, server);    /* setea el socket a conexion ssl */

    if ( SSL_connect(ssl) < 0 )   /* conecta con el servidor */
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);

    else{   

        printf("CONECTADO CON ENCRIPTACION %s\n\n", SSL_get_cipher(ssl));
        MuestraCertificados(ssl);        /* muestra los certificados */

        printf("\nMANDAS: ");
        scanf("%s", msg);

        SSL_write(ssl, msg, strlen(msg));   /* encripta y manda el mensaje */
        bytes = SSL_read(ssl, buf, sizeof(buf)); /* obtiene respuesta y desencripta */

        buf[bytes] = 0;
        printf("RECIBO: %s\n", buf);
        SSL_free(ssl);        /* libera el estado de conexion */
    }

    close(server);         /* cierra el socket */
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);        /* libera el contexto */
    return 0;
}
```

and the server code:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include "openssl/ssl.h"
#include "openssl/err.h"

int CreaEscuchador(int port){

    int sd;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;

    sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    bzero(&addr, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    if ( bind(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0 )
    {
        perror("no se puede vincular puerto");
        abort();
    }
    if ( listen(sd, 10) != 0 )
    {
        perror("no se puede configurar puerto de escucha");
        abort();
    }
    return sd;
}

SSL_CTX* InitServerCTX(void){

    SSL_CTX *ctx;

    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();  /* carga y registra todos los cifrados etc */
    SSL_load_error_strings();   /* carga todos los mensajes de error */
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_server_method());   /* crea un contexto para la instancia del servidor */
    if ( ctx == NULL )
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }
    return ctx;
}

void CargarCertificados(SSL_CTX* ctx, char* CertFile, char* KeyFile){

    if (SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, CertFile, KeyFile) != 1)
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);

    if (SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths(ctx) != 1)
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);

    /* setea el certificado local a traves de CertFile */
    if (SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, CertFile , SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0){
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }

    /* setea la clave privada a traves de keyFile (puede ser igual que certfile) */
    if (SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, KeyFile, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0){
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }

    /* verifica la clave privada */
    if (!SSL_CTX_check_private_key(ctx)){
        fprintf(stderr, "la clave privada no coincide con el certificado publico\n");
        abort();
    }

    //fuerza al cliente a tener un certificado
    SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx, SSL_VERIFY_PEER, NULL);
}

void MuestraCertificados(SSL* ssl)
{   X509 *cert;
    char *line;

    cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl); /* obtiene los certificados */
    if ( cert != NULL )
    {
        printf("CERTIFICADOS EN EL SERVIDOR:\n");
        line = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), 0, 0);
        printf("SUJETO: %s\n", line);
        free(line);
        line = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_issuer_name(cert), 0, 0);
        printf("EMISOR: %s\n", line);
        free(line);
        X509_free(cert);
    }
    else
        printf("NO EXISTEN CERTIFICADOS.\n");
}

void Servlet(SSL* ssl) /* servicio del servidor */
{   char buf[1024];
    char reply[1024];
    int sd, bytes;
    const char* echo="%s\n";

    if ( SSL_accept(ssl) < 0 )     /* hace el accept ssl */
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    else
    {
        MuestraCertificados(ssl);        /* muestra los certificados */
        bytes = SSL_read(ssl, buf, sizeof(buf)); /* recibe el mensaje */
        if ( bytes > 0 )
        {
            buf[bytes] = 0;
            printf("RECIBO: %s\n", buf);
            sprintf(reply, echo, buf);   /* contruyo la respuesta */
            SSL_write(ssl, reply, strlen(reply)); /* mando la respuesta */
        }
        else
            ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    }
    sd = SSL_get_fd(ssl);       /* coge la conexion del socket */
    SSL_free(ssl);         /* libera la conexion ssl */
    close(sd);          /* cierra la conexion */
}

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{   SSL_CTX *ctx;
    int server;

    if(argc != 4)
    return -1;

    SSL_library_init();

    ctx = InitServerCTX();        /* inicilaiza SSL */
    CargarCertificados(ctx, argv[2], argv[3]); /* carga los certificados */

    server = CreaEscuchador(atoi(argv[1]));    /* crea el escuchador */
    while (1){

        struct sockaddr_in addr;
        socklen_t len = sizeof(addr);
        SSL *ssl;

        int client = accept(server, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, &len);  /* acepta la conexion como siempre */

        printf("CONEXION: %s:%d\n",inet_ntoa(addr.sin_addr), ntohs(addr.sin_port));

        ssl = SSL_new(ctx);              /* coge le nuevo estado ssl con el contexto */
        SSL_set_fd(ssl, client);      /* setea el socket a conexion ssl */
        Servlet(ssl);         /* servicio del servidor */
    }
    close(server);          /* cierra el socket */
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);         /* libera el contexto */
}
```

to generate my certificates I use a root certificate:

```
openssl genrsa -out rootkey.pem 2048
openssl req -new -x509 -key rootkey.pem -out rootcert.pem
```

then I create a client and a server cert:

```
openssl genrsa -out clientkey.pem 2048
openssl req -new -key clientkey.pem -out client_solicit.csr
openssl x509 -req -CAcreateserial -in client_solicit.csr -CA rootcert.pem -CAkey rootkey.pem -out clientcert.pem

//same lines to server cert
```

Comment: Whats the error? Please indicate the error seen with `ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);`

Comment: '//fuerza al cliente a tener un certificado     SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx, SSL_VERIFY_PEER, NULL);' - can you remove this line from server code and see how things go ?

Answer (score 1):

done! the arguments of `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations` were wrong. The cert file points to a file of CA certificates in PEM format.

```
SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, "rootcert.pem", "rootkey.pem") != 1)
```